# How to add a custom admin menu on WORDPRESS?

Tags: wordpress

I've been reading some documentation in wordpress of add_menu_page() but I don't know how exactly how I'm gonna do it I'm a bit confused. I'am aiming to create a new Admin-Menu called "Tours", that has the same functionalities as Post-Menu-Page.

On my project I am currently posting/publishing Tours on Post-Page-Menu with News & Update. So my Post-Page-Menu Consists of 2 types of categories tours and news-&-update.

I want to have a dedicated Admin-Menu for tours to let the editor edit content easily and the contents is organized and the Post-Page-Menu will only have 1 task to do is to create a post of news-&-update.

Is it doable? or is there any plugin that can help me doing with this? But for me i prefer if I'll do it hard coded.

Comment: Sounds as though you'd like to register a custom post type. The [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) is fairly extensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two methods of achieving the same goal here all depends on experience you can add a custom post type to your theme via code by registering custom post type in your functions [read more here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) or you can use a plugin like [Custom post type UI](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) both methods will achieve your goal

Comment: Sorry took me long to reply, I forgot to reply my bad. But hey thanks! I made it by using the Custom post type UI.

Comment: glad i could help